# Minus operator in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a sql query with minus.

I have query1 which returns 28 rows with 2 columns
I have query2 which returns 22 row2 with same 2 columns in query 2.

when I create a query query1 minus query 2 it should have only show the 28-22=6 rows.
But it showing up all the 28 rows returned by query1.

Please advise.

Comment: Which database are you targetting? I've only ever used `minus` on oracle, personally. I know it doesn't strictly exist in this form on Sql Server, for example.

Comment: Post your query and some example data from both sides of the minus?

Comment: (Assuming oracle) For `minus` to work, the entire row must match exactly.

Comment: Well, apparently none of the tuples returned by `query2` show up as rows in `query1`.

Comment: -1 for never responding to questions about what rdbms this is.

Answer (score 11):

Try using EXCEPT instead of MINUS. For Example:
Lets consider a case where you want to find out what tasks are in a table that haven't been assigned to you(So basically you are trying to find what tasks could be available to do).

```
SELECT TaskID, TaskType
FROM Tasks
EXCEPT
SELECT TaskID, TaskType
FROM Tasks
WHERE Username = 'Vidya'
```

That would return all the tasks that haven't been assigned to you. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

If MINUS won't work for you, the general form you want is the main query in the outer select and a variation of the other query in a not exists clause.

```
select <insert list of fields here>
from mytable a
join myothertable b 
on b.aId = a.aid
where not exists (select * from tablec c where a.aid = c.aid)
```

Answer (score 2):

The fields might not be exactly alike. may be one of the fields is char(10) and the other is char(20) and they both have the string "TEST" in them. They might "look" the same.

If the database you are working on supports "INTERSECT", try this query and see how many are perfectly matching results.

```
select field1, field2 from table1
intersect 
select field1, field2 from table2
```

To get the results you are expecting, this query should give you 22 rows.

Comment: The OP is looking for 6 rows, not 22 (assuming 26 is a typo).

Comment: If 22 rows are common in query 1 and query2, then the MINUS query would give the 6 rows that are not common to both the rows. My answer was to confirm that the data is as the OP expects it to be.

Comment: this is not what OP asks. This does not answer the question.

Comment: The actual query is already given by the other answers. I am trying to explain how he can find out the *issue* (why the query is not working as he expects it to).

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
select field1, field2, . field_n
 from tables
 MINUS
 select field1, field2, . field_n
 from tables;
```

Answer (score 1):

MINUS works on the same principle as it does in the set operations. Suppose if you have set A and B,
A = {1,2,3,4}; B = {3,5,6}
then, A-B = {1,2,4}

If A = {1,3,5} and B = {2,4,6}
then, A-B = {1,3,5}. Here the count(A) before and after the MINUS operation will be the same, as it does not contain any overlapping terms with set B.

On similar lines, may be the result set obtained in query 2 may not have matching terms with the result of query1. Hence you are still getting 28 instead of 6 rows.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the difference records in the upper query which are not contained by the second query.

In your case for example 
A={1,2,3,4,5...28} AND  B={29,30}   then A-B={1,2,3....28}