# In sqlite3: looking for SELECT query for an actual composition of members of a certain group

Tags: php, sqlite

given that I have a table with events of members joining and leaving groups of the type

```
member_id| action | group   | ts
----------------------------------------
member_1 | joins  | group_a | 1445017260
member_2 | joins  | group_b | 1445017551
member_2 | leaves | group_b | 1445017580
member_3 | joins  | group_a | 1445017860
member_4 | joins  | group_b | 1445017951
member_3 | leaves | group_a | 1445017980
member_3 | joins  | group_b | 1445017990
member_5 | joins  | group_b | 1445018051
member_6 | joins  | group_a | 1445018580
...
```

and I would like to determine who is in a specific group for a specific timestamp.

E.g. who is in group_b for the timestamp 1445018680 (after all events in this case) the desired output is:

```
[member_3, member_4, member_5]
```

I'm using php and sqlite3. At the moment I only see the chance to iterate over all existing members and do a select as follows:

```
$inMembers = array();
$ts    = 1445018680;
$group = "group_b";

foreach($members as $member){

  $action = $DB->Select("SELECT * FROM events_$eventid WHERE group = :group AND event_ts <= :ts ORDER BY event_ts DESC LIMIT 1", array(
    "ts"    => $ts,
    "group" => $group,
  ));

  if($action == "joins") $inMembers[] = $member;

}
```

The DB object is an abstraction layer. I hope it's clear what I mean. I'm guessing there is a more elegant solution to that. Maybe without a loop. With a query just requiring a TS.

Thanks for help.
Lspreee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gets the latest timestamp for each group member:

```sql
SELECT member_id,
       MAX(event_ts)
FROM events_xxx
WHERE group = :group
  AND event_ts <= :ts
GROUP BY member_id;
```

To get the other columns of these rows, join this back to the original table:

```sql
SELECT events.member_id
FROM events_xxx
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT member_id,
                     MAX(event_ts) AS event_ts
              FROM events_xxx
              WHERE group = :group
                AND event_ts <= :ts
              GROUP BY member_id
             ) AS latest_events
WHERE events.action = 'joins';
```

Comment: I failed to execute the query, and at the moment I don't know why. First, many of the clauses are new to me (e.g. NATURAL JOIN) and I'd have to elaborate now...
 Second: is the "latest_events" something you set? Or something you expect to find in the database structure? I ask, since this is the only field that is not in my database structure. Thank you very much.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause). AS creates an alias name.

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading now. One last question that helps me: when you set FROM to the table "events" in the outer and the inner query, did you mean my events table? Or has it something to do with subqueries? http://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-or-subquery.html. I'm asking because  in my example the table name is events_$eventid, so usually something like events_140521688422.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$inMembers = array();
$ts    = 1445018680;
$action = "joins";

$inMembers = $DB->Select("SELECT * FROM events_$event_id WHERE group =   :group AND event_ts <= :ts AND action = :act ORDER BY event_ts DESC", array(
"ts"    => $ts,
"group" => $group,
"act" => $action
));
```

it's about storing 'join' or other action in a variable called $action and then make the query, or if you are interested only in action join you can simply hardcode the value.
Your code is a little bit pointless to me... you make the same query in a for loop why? And why you don't select the action with the query as i did?

Comment: Oh, thanks. But I'm looking for a solution that works with ANY timestamp. Not only timestamps of the actual event marks.

Comment: put the timestamp into a variable, can we see what have you done so far?

Comment: Sorry for being so vague in the first place. Updated my question.

Comment: This way you won't answer the question "who is in group_b at the time x", which is the desired question. Why? Because members can have joined the group and left the group by that time, so they're no longer in the group. See in the example member_2. It left already so it should not appear in the output array. If I just query for "join" attributes the member is still in the group. It doesn't change anything if the action is stored in a variable. I need to consider both actions at a time. My code (at least) does this, but can be computationally expensive, I guess.

Comment: maybe the keyword EXCEPT could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197193/minus-operator-in-sql
be carefull because you could exclude people that made a join after a leave

Comment: I didn't know about EXCEPT. But it won't solve my problems: with EXCEPT I'm able to substract my selection by an independet second selection. The key thing is: they're unrelated. I'd need something like:
Select all items with "joins" THAT have no later "leaves". That THAT can't be reflected in the EXCEPT.